# LibreOffice Error after installed in centos 7

Tags: centos7, libreoffice, soffice

/opt/libreoffice6.3/program/oosplash: error while loading shared libraries: libuno_sal.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

i'm using centos7

Comment: What should `apache poi` have to do with this problem?

Comment: How did you install LibreOffice? If not from rpm, why not try a package managed version which includes dependencies?